# How to make a UIView gradient effect using 3 colors

Tags: swift, uiview, gradient, swift4.2

I want to use a center color as well. Can someone please help me with this?

```
extension UIView {
    func setGradientBackground(topColor: UIColor, bottomColor: UIColor) {
        let gradientLayer       = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame     = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors    = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint    = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint      = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding another color in your `gradientLayer.colors` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:

```
gradientLayer.colors = [topColor.cgColor, <centerColor.cgColor>,bottomColor.cgColor]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0] //you can remove this line if you want even gradient.
```

`gradientLayer.colors` and `gradientLayer.locations` are not limited to just two inputs each.

Also, as far as `startPoint` and `endPoint` default to (0.5,0.0) and (0.5,1.0) respectively. You can refer to what this would look like here:

http://ios-tutorial.com/create-uiview-gradient-background/

Comment: Thank You. This link http://ios-tutorial.com/create-uiview-gradient-background/ helped.

Comment: I wanted purple on the top, white in the middle and again purple at the bottom. It worked after using this <gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]> with 3 colours.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad you were able to work it out. Would you mark this question as answered? :)

Comment: sure sure. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a gradient using :

```
func addGradient(){
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor,UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.green.cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    gradient.locations = [0,0.5,1]
    self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
}
```

//Here self is a UIView

endPoints are used with respect to the UIView's bound. This decides the direction of the gradient.

locations is used to decide where the colors must be.